New Minka Aire ceiling fan is making this tapping noise
My wife and I got a new Minka Aire Light Wave ceiling fan for our 1965 townhouse, and it's been making a tapping noise that's been keeping me awake. We tried installing a longer downrod since it was so close to the ceiling, and that did make the noise a bit quieter but hasn't stopped it. It tends to start only after a few hours of use, which makes it hard for an electrician to really solve it.
Here's video of the noise (taken before we got the longer downrod): https://imgur.com/a/3M0be1c
If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, we'd be grateful.

In my experience this is a symptom of a box that is not fan rated, and which therefore has too much flex. The box that the fan is mounted to should indicate that it is suitable for a fan; if it doesn't you'll need to get an old work fan-rated box to replace it with.

hey, thanks so much for this response. I didn't know anything about fan boxes. will check on ours and see if that's it.
